# PacketFu timestamps

Tags: ruby, libpcap

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the PacketFu timestamp struct. ([PacketFu docs](http://packetfu.com/doc/) - [timestamp doc](http://www.rdoc.info/github/todb/packetfu/PacketFu/Timestamp)) I'm doing

```
packets = PcapFile.read_packets "myCapture.pcap"
```

... but I have no idea how to get the timestamp information out of the result. Unix epoch format would be fine.

I'm aware that timestamp info is part of `libpcap` and not the actual packets, and I've confirmed (in Wireshark) that useful timestamp information is present. I want to extract it programatically.

---

Here's what I gleaned from the [Packetfu test code](https://github.com/todb/packetfu/blob/ef07700e68775835b6d5137c0b66bc3ff6a5bf85/examples/simple-stats.rb#L22):

```
file = File.open("myCapture.pcap") {|f| f.read}
packets = PacketFu::PcapPackets.new.read file
packets.each { |p|
    t = p.timestamp
    puts t.sec.to_i.to_s + "." + t.usec.to_i.to_s
    packet = PacketFu::Packet.parse(p.data)
    # do stuff with packet...
}
```

Horrendously undocumented, and <s>probably kills performance to have to read in the whole file instead of passing a block as can be done with `PcapFile.read_packets`</s> is surprisingly far more performant than `PcapFile.read_packets`??? (It's an anecdotal, not scientific, result.)

---

I'll accept an answer noticeable nicer than the above.

Also, if someone with sufficient rep could create a `packetfu` tag, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. So I extended PacketFu to solve it. I hope this will help you.

```
require 'packetfu'

module PacketFu
  class Timestamp
    def to_f
      sec.to_i + (usec.to_i / 1000000.0)
    end
  end

  class PcapFile
    def self.read_packets_with_timestamp(fname, &block)
      count = 0
      packets = [] unless block
      read(fname) do |packet| 
        pkt = Packet.parse(packet.data.to_s)
        pkt.timestamp = packet.timestamp.to_f
        if block
          count += 1
          yield pkt
        else
          packets << pkt
        end
      end
      block ? count : packets
    end
  end

  class Packet
    attr_accessor :timestamp
  end
end

PacketFu::PcapFile.read_packets_with_timestamp('xxx.pcap') {|pkt|
  if pkt.is_ip? and pkt.is_tcp?
    puts "[#{pkt.timestamp}] #{pkt.ip_src_readable}(#{pkt.tcp_sport}) -> #{pkt.ip_dst_readable}(#{pkt.tcp_dport})"
  end
}
```